# Date-fns and Moment different results

Tags: javascript, momentjs, date-fns

I have this date string: `2020-01-21` and I get two different results between Date-Fns and Moment:

```
Date-fns: {format(new Date(startTime), 'MMM d, y')} => Jan 20, 2020
Moment:  {moment(startTime).format('MMM Do, YYYY')} => Jan 21st, 2020
```

Comment: Try using `parseISO` in date-fns, I believe that is the now recommended way to parse a date string.

Comment: That worked thank you. If you want to give that as an answer i can close this

Comment: Which result is supposed to be right? If you want `21st` with `date-fns` simply replace `d` with `do`.

Comment: I added an answer - glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`date-fns` made a change recently to [how a string is parsed into a date](https://date-fns.org/v2.10.0/docs/parseISO). The current best practice would be to use `parseISO` as follows:

```
parseISO('2020-01-21')
```

The problem actually occurs before `date-fns` - in a browser console the following:

```
new Date('2020-01-21')
```

shows an incorrect date.